# opendirectoryd: macOS wants to make changes

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

After I upgraded to OSX Mojave I keep "getting macOS wants to make changes" repeatedly regardless of what I do. I have tried everything with no success, here is a list:

- Reset login keys on keychain
- Wipe keychain folder
- Reset opendirectoryd.

A picture of the panel itself:

[macOS wants to make changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epteb.png)

Just some more context, when I insert my admin user and password I see the following error on the console (thus my suspicion that is has something to do with opendirectoryd).

```
error   13:19:59.233183 +0200   opendirectoryd  near "check": syntax error
error   13:20:00.789307 +0200   callservicesd   Remote loader crashed for request: <private>
error   13:20:00.791129 +0200   callservicesd    => Retrying... (0/5) retries
```

Does anybody have some idea of what else I could try?

PS: An image of the

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
José.

Answer (score 0):

Standard 'first fixes for random weirdness'...

- Run the latest Combo updater, whether or not you're already up to date - Apple KB - [Download macOS Mojave 10.14.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1996)
- Re-lay the OS from Recovery > Reinstall macOS - this will reset the OS without affecting your user data - Apple KB - [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314)